# How to delete a service principal from the sql admin settings page?

Tags: azure-databricks

I have created a service principal (as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/admin/data-access-configuration#storage-access)), but I now need to delete it.

I can't see a UI option to delete this - how else can I delete it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was here:

```bash
databricks_endpoint=<<myendpoint>>

curl -n -X GET https://${databricks_endpoint}/api/2.0/sql/config/warehouses > my.json

# EDIT JSON TO REMOVE UNWANTED PARAMETERS

curl -n -X PUT -d @my.json https://${databricks_endpoint}/api/2.0/sql/config/warehouses
```